# Array from dictionary weird state

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, enums

I have the following dictionary created in a parent view model:

```
var filtersDict: [FKey: [Filter]] = [:]

init(...) {
  ...
  for key in FKey.allCases {
       filtersDict[key] = []
  }
}
```

I'm passing this object via dependency injection down a navigation stack. Let's call it A to B . In B, I'm adding an object like so:

```
self.filtersDict[FKey.categories]?.append(filter)
```

In B everything is fine, I can see my data. When going back to A, when reading `self.filtersDict[FKey.categories]` array count is 0. What am I missing here ? Shouldn't it be the same object ?

Many thanks

Comment: Swift `Dictionary` is **value** type not the **reference** type.

Comment: (... which means when you inject it into the child VC you create a new, isolated copy, and so changes don't filter down to the instance in the parent VC.)

Comment: Damn, in objective-c arrays and dictionares are reference types. I could have sworn it was the same in swift. Thanks a lot anyway !